# Rails - how to write a method that uses attributes from different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to write a method in my user model, that shows the user's full name and the title of the organisation that the user is from, in one line.

In my user model, I have a method called full_name, which works to add the first name and last name attributes together. That part works.

Now, I'm trying to write a method called 'formal_title', which adds the user's full name to an organisation.title.

I have models for User and Organisation. The associations are:

User

```
belongs_to :organisation
```

Organisation

```
has_many :users
```

My organisation table has an attribute called :title.

My attempt at writing a method in my user model is:

```
def full_name
    if first_name.present?
      [*first_name.capitalize, last_name.capitalize].join(" ")
    else
      test_full_name
    end
  end

  def organisation_title
    Organisation.title.where(organisation.id == self.organisation_id).titleize
  end

  def formal_title
        [*self.full_name, self.organisation_title].join(",")
    end
```

When I try this, I get an error in the console that says:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `formal_title' for #<User:0x007fea3495fe90>
```

This error message makes no sense to me because the user that I'm testing this on has a first name, last name and organisation id to test against. the organisation_id in the user table references an organisation that has a title, so I'm lost as to why any part of this method could be missing but also confused about what the console doesn't know about the method.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

**Entire user model has:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify strict: true # strict means you get true only on a role that you manually add
  attr_accessor :current_role


  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
                 :confirmable, :lockable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [ :linkedin, :twitter, :orcid ]


  # --------------- associations

  belongs_to :organisation, optional: true

  has_one :device
  has_many :identities, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :setting, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :org_request, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :proposals, dependent: :destroy

  # Conversations
  has_many :authored_conversations, class_name: 'Conversation', foreign_key: 'author_id'
  has_many :received_conversations, class_name: 'Conversation', foreign_key: 'received_id'
  has_many :personal_messages, dependent: :destroy
  # End Conversations

  # teams
  has_many :teams, foreign_key: "team_mate_id"
  has_many :team_projects, through: :teams, source: :proposal
  has_many :received_invitations, :class_name => "TeamInvitation", :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'
  has_many :sent_invitations, :class_name => "TeamInvitation", :foreign_key => 'sender_id'




  # --------------- scopes

  # --------------- validations

  validates :first_name, presence:  { message: 'First name cannot be blank.' }
  validates :last_name, presence:   { message: 'Last name cannot be blank.'  }
  validates :email,     format:     { with: EMAIL_REGEX }
  validates :email,     uniqueness: { message: 'This email is already associated with an account. Try logging in.'}

   # validates_format_of :first_name, with: /a-zA-Z/
   # validates_format_of :last_name, with: /a-zA-Z/
   # validates_length_of :password, within: 8..128


  # --------------- class methods

  def full_name
    if first_name.present?
      [*first_name.capitalize, last_name.capitalize].join(" ")
    else
      "test_full_name"
    end
  end

  def organisation_title
  # you don't need to do `Organisation.where...` here because you have defined the `belongs_to` association for `:organisation`. So, it will directly give you the `Organisation` object.
    organisation.title.titleize
  end

  def formal_title
        [*self.full_name, self.organisation_title].join(",")
    end
  # --------------- instance methods
  def online?
    true
    # false
    # !Redis.new.get("user_#{self.id}_online").nil?
  end



end
```

Comment: Make sure you are reloading your rails console by calling `reload!` in console.

Comment: @dnsh - I reload! every time.

Comment: what rails version is this?

Comment: rails 5, ruby 2.3.1

Comment: hmm i dont use rails 5, but your code looks completely wrong to me

Comment: please post what you type in the console

Comment: u  = User.last then u.formal_title

Comment: I would appreciate feedback on why this question is down voted. If there is a resource to learn how to do this, I'd gratefully accept a reference to it.

Comment: @Mel: Please post you full `app/models/user.rb` class. Btw did you restart your console after adding the `formal_title` to your class?

Comment: I did reload! after I added the changes to my class. I think that's the same as restarting the console

Comment: I added my full user model to the post above

Comment: your "class methods" are also "instance methods"

Comment: try to restart (not reload!) your console, your app might not set-up as you think

Comment: or an error i like to do: not saving the .rb file :)

Comment: @Fallenhero - I don't know what you mean. I save my changes each time. then I reload! in the console. Then I try to test.

Comment: see answer by sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I save my changes each time. then I `reload!` in the console.

Not enough. You should either restart the console or re-query the user.

```
u = User.find(u.id)
```

`reload!` doesn't affect already loaded objects, so the user you had there, it won't see the new method.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change your code like this and let me know what it gives:

```
def full_name
  if first_name.present?
    [first_name.capitalize, last_name.capitalize].join(" ")
  else
    test_full_name  # will work if test_full_name is defined inside this class
  end
end

def organisation_title
  # you don't need to do `Organisation.where...` here because you have defined the `belongs_to` association for `:organisation`. So, it will directly give you the `Organisation` object.
  organisation.title.titleize
end

def formal_title
  [self.full_name, self.organisation_title].join(",")
end
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the suggestion. I still get this error: u.formal_title
NoMethodError: undefined method `formal_title' for #<User:0x007fea3495fe90>

Comment: No need to prefix getters with `self`.

Comment: @Jagdeep - thanks for this. Your version of the organisation title worked. I just couldn't get the results from the console without restarting. I didn't know that reloading wasnt enough. Thanks so much for the help.